# Understanding how this rspec gem works

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to get this gem to work but not having much luck. Although this is puppet related, my questions hopefully aren't.

I am trying to understand what the following `:rspec` if statement is implying:

```
module RSpecHieraPuppet
  module HieraDefaultConfiguration
    extend RSpec::SharedContext
    let(:hiera_config) do
      { :backends => ['rspec'],
        :rspec => respond_to?(:hiera_data) ? hiera_data : {} } # this one
    end
  end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/amfranz/rspec-hiera-puppet/blob/master/lib/rspec-hiera-puppet/rspec.rb

Can someone clarify what `? hiera_data` means here? I can't seem to find any reference to it in the gem's source.

My understanding is that from the gem's example usage, the respond to is watching for the trigger in the example response:

```
let(:hiera_data) do
  {  
    :key123  => ['abc'],
  }
end
```

But I can't seem to trace what happens after it triggers because I dont see any connection to  `rspec_backend.rb` file which is in charge of handling this.

Any help tracing the calls made here would be appreciated. (gem only has 3 files to work with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if you have defined a

```
let(:hiera_data) { {:key => 'value'} }
```

that will be the value of the :rspec key. That's because in that case the object in scope responds to hiera_data. Otherwise the value will be {}.

For info on the syntax of respond_to? [read here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F)

I think that's what you're asking.

Comment: I was confused as to what `hiera_data` is. I'm fairly new to ruby so I couldn't understand why the respond_to is checking for the symbol `hiera_data` and why it true value for the statement isnt a symbol

Comment: That's the syntax of respond_to?; you pass the name of the method you're checking for as a symbol. If true, you're actually calling (sending) the method to self. I have added a link in my response with info about respond_to?